# ProgressDialog disappearing after some time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an Android app with an AsyncTask, that does some synchronization from a database. While the task is performing, a ProgressDialog, started from the Task, is shown and updated after each synced peace of data. The whole task takes about 30-40 mins and runs good and clean every time. But afer about 20 mins the ProgressDialog disappears for some reason, while the task carries on.
I don't know why that happens... even if you hit the home button its still there. Is there some kind of trick oder workaround to fix this?

Here is my relevant code:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setTitle("Synchronisiere Datenbank...");
    this.dialog.setMessage("Datenbank wird synchronisiert. Dieser Vorgang     kann einige Minuten dauern");
    dialog.setView(bar);
    this.dialog.show();
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d("", "" + result);
    System.out.println("FEDDIG");

    try {
        if (this.dialog != null && this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (!uploadSuccessful) {
        showErrorDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: "even if you hit the home button its still there" ...what does that mean? dint get you...

Comment: i meant, that even switching to another app or pressing the phones home (or menu) button does not close the dialog... sorry for the bad expression

Comment: But you said `afer about 20 mins the ProgressDialog disappears` .. Now, what is the exact problem that you are facing? Is the ProgressDialog dismissing or not?

Comment: On a side note, you are using AsyncTask for a 30-40 minutes process. Seriously? Why not Service?

Comment: @Lal the problem is that is dismissing too  early. it should stay until the task is onPostExecute() ...but it's dismissing before that

Comment: @Pynnie how do you know that the code in `doInBackground()` has not yet finished even after the `dialog` has been dismissed?

Comment: @Lal : He updates the progress piece wise after each parts of task complete. That's how.

Comment: @Lal pulp_fiction is right. I also do some logging on the console for debugging and that shows me that the process is not done yet